# #DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
    Name    Sex Age Height  Weight
0   Alfred  M   14  69.0    112.5
1   Alice   F   13  56.5    84.0
2   Barbara F   13  65.3    98.0
3   Carol   F   14  62.8    102.5
4   Henry   M   14  63.5    102.5
5   James   M   12  57.3    83.0
6   Jane    F   12  59.8    84.5
7   Janet   F   15  62.5    112.5
8   Jeffrey M   13  62.5    84.0
9   John    M   12  59.0    99.5
10  Joyce   F   11  51.3    50.5
11  Judy    F   14  64.3    90.0
12  Louise  F   12  56.3    77.0
13  Mary    F   15  66.5    112.0
14  Philip  M   16  72.0    150.0
15  Robert  M   12  64.8    128.0
16  Ronald  M   15  67.0    133.0
17  Thomas  M   11  57.5    85.0
18  William M   15  66.5    112.0
```

I want output F and M alternatively from the above dataset using pandas `DataFrame`.

Comment: What's the name of the frame?

Comment: Class dataframe

Comment: _Class dataframe_ is not a variable _name_.